# Displaying post based on users location using the Haversine formula

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom post type called "event" that has acf with latitude and longitude. Im tying to get the distance for all "events" that are related to the post
Im using geoplugin.com to get the users Lat & long.

```
$geoplugin  = unserialize( file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip=' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) );
    $geoiix    = $geoplugin['geoplugin_regionName'] ;
    $user_lat  = $geoplugin['geoplugin_latitude'];
    $user_long = $geoplugin['geoplugin_longitude'];

    $artist_id  = $tags[0]->term_id;
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'events',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
        'meta_key' => 'event_date',
        'tag__in' => array( $artist_id ),
         );
      $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
      if ($my_query->have_posts()) : while ($my_query->have_posts()) :
      $my_query->the_post();

       $event_lat  = get_field( 'gp_latitude' ); 
       $event_long = get_field( 'gp_longitude' ); 

       $earth_radius = 3960.00; # in miles
       $lat_1 = $event_lat;
       $lon_1 = $event_long;
       $lat_2 = $user_lat;
       $lon_2 = $user_long;
       $delta_lat = $lat_2 - $lat_1 ;
       $delta_lon = $lon_2 - $lon_1 ;

     function distance_haversine($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2) {
      global $earth_radius;
      global $delta_lat;
      global $delta_lon;
      $alpha    = $delta_lat/2;
      $beta     = $delta_lon/2;
       $a   = sin(deg2rad($alpha)) * sin(deg2rad($alpha)) + cos(deg2rad($lat1)) *           cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * sin(deg2rad($beta)) * sin(deg2rad($beta)) ;
      $c        = asin(min(1, sqrt($a)));
      $distance = 2*$earth_radius * $c;
      $distance = round($distance, 4);

      return $distance;
    }

     $hav_distance = distance_haversine($lat_1, $lon_1, $lat_2, $lon_2);
     echo $hav_distance;
     ?>
```

This code is breaking its shows 1 result and I cant seem to figure out why. I thought maybe the advanced custom fields plugin isn't the best way to store the lat and long.

Comment: your code is not closing if - while tag.

Comment: It is im just not showing it here

Comment: Did your event posts have ( all of them ) latitude and longitude meta_value?

Comment: Yes they all have lat and long values. Im using advanced custom fields plugin to make the meta fields

Comment: Are you sure you're using your `distance_haversine()` function and the `echo()` within the loop?

Comment: Yeah im pretty sure there both between  start of the loop and the endwhile & endif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have your function within your loop...everytime it runs you re-declare the function which throws a php error (you prob have php errors off)

Put the haversine function definition in your functions file.